# xv6 operating system - Implementation of triple indirection

Tags: c, xv6

The xv6 mkfs.c file declare the variables:

```
int nblocks = 985;
int nlog = LOGSIZE;
int ninodes = 200;
int size = 1024;
```

That declaration should work properly with inode that have 12 direct blocks and 1 indirect block, what i don't understand is why nblocks is defined as 985?
The number of blocks in one inode is 140 (128 for the indirect + 12 direct), so i don't fully understand where is 985 came from and also the size of 1024.

If i would understand that part i think i will be able to change the variables to support triple indirection.

Thanks!

Comment: this may be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30853617/xv6-crashes-when-trying-to-implement-triple-indirection-in-xv6-operating-system

Comment: yes, but still i don't understand the calculation behind it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An inode takes only 32 bytes on disk (`sizeof(struct inode)`). Only when writing to an inode it starts to take more space (blocks) on disk.

Notice this block of code:

```
bitblocks = size/(512*8) + 1;
usedblocks = ninodes / IPB + 3 + bitblocks;
...
assert(nblocks + usedblocks + nlog == size);
```